# Why does the animation effect run only once in framer motion?

Tags: css, animation, framer-motion

When I press a button, if it doesn't pass validation, I want to create an error animation effect in framer motion.

I want the effect to happen every time it doesn't pass validation, but currently the animation only happens initially, and no matter how many times I press the button after that, the animation doesn't happen.

What is the solution?

Since toast.error() continues to operate normally, there seems to be something strange about the framer motion code.

```js
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const nextHandler = () => {
    setError(false);

    if (!validate(value, [VALIDATION_TYPE.REQUIRE, VALIDATION_TYPE.MAX_LENGTH(5)])) {
      setError(true);
      toast.error(ERROR_MESSAGES.invalid_name);
      return;
    }

    nextStepHandler();
  };

        <motion.input
          type="text"
          id="userName"
          name="userName"
          autoComplete="off"
          value={value}
          onChange={inputHandler}
          initial={false}
          animate={{ // it animates only once
            borderColor: error ? 'red' : 'initial',
            x: error ? [-2, 2, -2, 2, 0] : 0,
          }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        />

        <button type="button" onClick={nextHandler}>
          Next
        </button>
```

Comment: Can you include more of your code? I made a [simple recreation](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/silly-wave-cqpgl2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A40%2C14) of your setup and it's working as expected.

Comment: thank you. Solved.

As you said, it was an asynchronous issue.

nextStepHandler also

  const nextStepHandler = () => {
    setDirection('next');
    setStepIndex((prevStepIndex) => prevStepIndex + 1);
    setStep(steps[stepIndex + 1]);
  };

Since it was a function that simply deals with the state, I didn't know the cause, but thanks to you, I found it.

Comment: Nice! glad you got it figures out.